# Etymology of words used to start and ask questions

Tags: etymology

Could you please help me understand the etymology of words used to start questions? I am particularly interested by the words 'how' and 'why'. Thank you!

Comment: I think that your question is too broad. Maybe the site https://english.stackexchange.com is the place where you should ask about etymology but after doing some research on your own. You have to ask more specific questions, about a particular aspect of the etimology of those words that you don't understand or find difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The OED gives them both as coming from Old English:

- **how** Old English *hú* < **hwó*, corresponding to Old Frisian *hû*, *hô*, Old Saxon *hwô*, *hwuo*, *wô* (Middle Dutch *hoe* (*ho, hou*), Dutch *hoe*, Middle Low German *woe*), Old High German (Tatian) *wuo* < Germanic **hwô*, an adverbial formation from the interrogative pronoun stem *hwa*- who? Parallel to Middle Dutch *hú*, and to Gothic *hwaiwa*, Old High German *hweo*, *weo*, *wio*, German *wie*, with different suffixes.
- **why** Old English *hwí* , *hwý* instrumental case of *hwæt* what pron., adj.1, adv., int., conj., and n., governed by *to* or *for* (see forwhy adv. and conj.) or used simply as adverb, corresponding to Old Saxon *hwî* used with prepositions (*bi hwî* , *te hwî* ) and simply = why, wherefore, Old Norse *hví* used as dative of *hvat* , and as adverb = why (Middle Swedish, Danish *hvi* ) < Old Germanic **χwī* < Indo-European **qwei* , locative < **qwo-* who pron.; compare Greek (Doric) *πεῖ* where.